# Send message and image to specific number with ACTION_SEND

Tags: android

I am trying to send a text message to a specific phone number. I want the message to include both an attached image (png) and a text body.

```
var shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage)
shareIntent.putExtra("address", "smsto:5555555555")
shareIntent.type = "image/png"
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "SHARE"))
```

I'm expecting to be able to choose the default messaging app and then to have the phone number pre-populated and the message containing the image and body text.

What's actually happening is one of two things:

1) If I use a phone number that exists in my contact book, everything works except there's no image attached.

2) If I use a phone number that does *not* exist in my contact book, only the phone number will be pre-populated and there is not body text or image.

Of note: If I remove

```
shareIntent.putExtra("address", "smsto:5555555555")
```

Then I am able to select the messaging app I want, choose a contact, and the message then contains both the image and the body text. So the problem appears to be some kind of conflict when providing the desired phone number to the intent.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I would like to do the same thing.

Comment: what is the answer?